# Find all primes $p$ such that $(2^{p-1}-1)/p$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all primes $p$ such that $(2^{p-1}-1)/p$ is a perfect square. I tried brute-force method and tried to find some pattern. I got $p=3,7$ as solutions. Apart from these I have tried for many other primes but couldn't find any other such prime.
Are these the only primes that satisfy the condition?

If yes, how to prove it theoretically and if not, how to find others?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hint: Let $p=2k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N},$ then $2^{2k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)=pm^2.$ We know that $\gcd(2^k-1,2^k+1)=1$ since they are consecutive odd integers, so the equation breaks into $2^k-1=px^2, 2^k+1=y^2$ or $2^k-1=x^2, 2^k+1=py^2.$

Easy investigation shows that the only solutions are $p=3,7.$ I will leave it to you to fill the gaps. You may also interested in [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient)

Comment: Very good explanation.. +1.

Comment: @ehsanmo: thanks.your hint really helped.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: how to solve this equations?

Comment: @Avatar how to solve this equations? with answers$3,7$

Comment: @agustin: Take case $1$ when $2^k-1=px^2,2^k+1=y^2$, $\\$ then $y^2-1=2^k\implies(y+1)(y-1)=2^k\implies y+1=2^m,y-1=2^n$ form some $m,n\in \Bbb N\cup\{0\} \\$ which gives  $2^m-2^n=2$. Now, the only possible value of $m,n$ is $2,1$ respectively. Therefore, $y=3\implies k=3$. $\\$ Putting $k=3$ in $2^k-1=px^2$ gives $px^2=7$. Since $7$ is a prime $\implies p=7$. Similarly, following case $2$ gives $p=3$

Comment: RE Case 2: $2^k-1=x^2 \Rightarrow 2^k = x^2+1 \Rightarrow 2^k \mod 4 \in \{1,2\}$ which gives $k\in \{0,1\}$.